# Is there any relativistic constraint on the rate of change of a scalar field?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, higgs, boundary-conditions, classical-field-theory

Consider a scalar field $\phi(t, x, y, z)$ obeying the waves equation with an Higgs-like potential (the "mexican hat"):
$$\tag{1}
\mathcal{V}(\phi) = \frac{\lambda}{4} (\phi^2 - \phi_0^2)^2,
$$
where $\lambda > 0$ and $\phi_0$ are constants.  $\phi_0$ is the value of the "true vacuum" field, which can be positive or negative.  The waves equation of motion of the self-interacting field is this (I'm using units such that $c \equiv 1$):
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2} + \lambda (\phi^2 - \phi_0^2) \, \phi = 0.
$$
To solve the waves equation (2), we need a consistent set of initial conditions and boundary conditions.  For the initial conditions, we usually give the field values at time $t = 0$ and its rate of change:
\begin{align}
\phi(0, x, y, z) &= \mathcal{F}(x, y, z), \tag{3} \\[2ex]
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \, \bigg|_{t = 0} &= \mathcal{G}(x, y, z). \tag{4}
\end{align}
As far as I know, there is no constraint on the values of $\phi(0, x, y, z)$, in the ***classical theory*** of relativistic fields.  The function $\mathcal{F}$ can be anything.

But is there any constraint on the values of the field *derivative*?  Can the function $\mathcal{G}$ be completely arbitrary too in relativity? (this time derivative is not the same as a real velocity, which of course is constrained by causality: $v < 1$).